# How to show loader in Global.asax Application_BeginRequest in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have multipage application and I want to show a loader on each request. 
Its not feasible to call loader function which is defined somewhere in common file.

Easiest way to implement this would be call a function single time in Application_BeginRequest.
I have tried but it's not possible for me to call javascript in this method.

Can you please guide me how can i call javascript method or write a javascript in Application_BeginRequest?

Thank you so much for any hint/solution.

Comment: In `BeginRequest` event, you have a scope of the server side request, there is not render output in this event, it executes before any instance of a controller and call a action method.

Comment: Yes you are right. Is there any work around? Or can we cll a javascript event in "OnActionExecuting" method?

Comment: In action filter, you can access the ViewBag, and pass some information to view, but, execute javascript, there is no way, it is a server side context.

Comment: Rather calling loading function each time on every event; Is there any other way to implement generic loader. Which will execute on every request and distroy in each request end?

Comment: I am not sure I understood this correct; What is a loader? are you talking about loading panel? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Put Javascript in your _Layout.cshtml page. Assuming of course all pages use the same common page.